# Session class error that requires an encryption key in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm new to codeigniter and have an okay experience with php. I recently encountered an error where codeigniter tells me

```
 "In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file."
```

And I heard the solution was to paste in

```
   $config['encryption_key'] = 'your_encryption_key_here';
```

in the config file.

Now I have absolutely no idea what just happened here. What is this encryption key? Why is it required for session class and what's the point?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Session class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> Note: Even if you are not using encrypted sessions, you must set an encryption key in your config file which is used to aid in preventing session data manipulation.

Also, you shouldn't need to paste anything. `$config['encryption_key']` already exists in `config.php` but is set to an empty string:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class or the Session class you
| MUST set an encryption key.  See the user guide for info.
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
```

Comment: We should downvote ourselfs for posting quotes that are clearly visible in the documentation :)

Comment: http://jeffreybarke.net/tools/codeigniter-encryption-key-generator/ - you can use this to generate the key :)

Comment: May I ask what the point of an encryption key is actually? I'm new to all of this.. sorry.

Comment: @Matt: From my answer above, the point of the key is `to aid in preventing session data manipulation.` You can read more in the [Encryption class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html). CodeIgniter is known for it's above-average documentation - I highly recommend reading through it.

Comment: @Philip - I suppose you could look at it as potentially easy rep points ;) In all seriousness, though, I agree with you and wish people would start with the documentation. In CodeIgniter's case, it really is quite good.

Comment: @Colin Yeah CI docs are pretty decent.  Still people overlook it and not just that for native php functions people also overlook the php docs.  I guess some people get lazy and if they cant find a solution in a video tutorial they come on here to ask these questions.  PS not directed at Matt in anyway.